# Permissions required for dynamic system functions

Tags: azure-sql-database

Using Azure SQL.
What is the tick to allow a server role the ability to access a dynamic system function?
Specifically `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object`.

When I try to execute this under a non admin account, the result set is empty.

Answer (score 0):

For a database user to be able to query or use Dynamic Management Views and functions, it will require to grant the user VIEW DATABASE STATE permission.

```
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO yourdatabaseuser WITH GRANT OPTION;
```